# Msal b2s popup login form redirect to /null

Tags: azure, vue.js, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I use msal.js in vue.js project to login user through azure b2c.

Everything is fine in local server, but when I change `redirect_uri` and publish the website online, after the user enters the auth data in azure login form, azure redirects to `{redirect_uri}/null`.

Sometimes it works correctly, but many times it doesn't.

Here my code

```
import * as Msal from 'msal';
app = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(
      {
        auth:
          { clientId: this.applicationConfig.clientID,
            authority: this.applicationConfig.authority,
            validateAuthority: this.applicationConfig.validateAuthority,
            redirectUri: this.applicationConfig.redirectUri }
      });
app.loginPopup(this.tokenRequest).then(
        loginResponse => {
          resolve(loginResponse);
        },
        error => {
          resolve(false);
        }
      );
```

Comment: Could you add some of your login code?

Comment: add my code to question content

Comment: This error seems strange, can you paste the value of the authority and redirectUri here? By the way, did you try it in a incognito window?